# ng-change doesn't works on item changed

Tags: angularjs

This is my HTML code:

```
<md-select ng-model="course" ng-change="getTeachers()">
    <md-option ng-repeat="x in courses" ng-value="x.title">
        {{x.title}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

and the function *getTeachers* is never called on item changed.
I don't understand why. I tried very hard.

Comment: post your controller

Answer (score 0):

you can use [watch](https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/) instead in your controller

```
$scope.$watch('course', function(newValue, oldValue) { 
// do whatever you want 
});
```